# Creating MacOS account via shell script

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to create a local administrator account on a number of machines and set it as the only administrator bar root using the below script. While the user is technically created and can be used for administrative tasks it cannot be signed into. Does anyone know what i'm missing?

```
#!/bin/bash

dscl . -create /Users/user
dscl . -create /Users/user UserShell /bin/bash
dscl . -create /Users/user RealName user
dscl . -create /Users/user UniqueID "510"
dscl . -create /Users/user PrimaryGroupID 20
dscl . -create /Users/user NFSHomeDirectory /Users/user
dscl . -passwd /Users/user password
dscl . -delete /Groups/admin GroupMembership
dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership root user
```

Tried using `dscl . create /Users/username IsHidden 0` but that did not seem to have any effect.

Comment: If you omit last two `dscl` statements, can you login with `user` ?

Comment: No, removing the local admin group membership commands did not seem to affect the login process.

Comment: Found the solution, seems the script never created a home folder, adding `createhomedir -c -u user` seems to have resolved the issue

Comment: Is `dscl . -create /Users/user NFSHomeDirectory /Users/user` supposed to create home folder ?

Comment: That's what i thought too but for some reason it wasn't doing that it simply set the variable for what is considered the user's home folder without checking if it even exists.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, seems the script never created a home folder, adding `createhomedir -c -u user` seems to have resolved the issue